# Zeolytes as Catalyst in hydrocracking

Tags: catalysis, hydrocarbons

What is the working principle that allows zeolites to be catalysts in hydrocracking? 
Is it only their acidic ability to hold hydrogen and release to crack the oil?

Comment: most probably its  because of the huge surface area provided by zeolytes